# I want to generate multiple Id's in entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So my question is: I would like to generate an incremented id on foreign key StudentId, but my gebruikerId is already the primary key with identity enable.
and the exception I get is: "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Gebruikers'. Only one identity column per table is allowed."
Which makes sense, but how is it possible to generate multiple Id generation in the same class/superclass.

```
public class Gebruiker
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int GebruikerId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Studenten")]
public partial class Student : Gebruiker
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentProjects = new List<StudentProject>();
        StudentSkills = new List<StudentSkill>();
        Rapporten = new List<Rapport>();
    }

    //not allowed but I need it.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to flesh out your question a bit more ;)

Comment: First I would ask why you need to do this at all? It's not something I've ever seen that is needed.

Comment: So I got a Leraar entity & Student entity which both inherit Gebruiker(means:User).

Comment: But Student entity might be linked to other tables hence he needs an generated Id, but gebruiker already uses this as a primary key

Comment: Are `Leraar` and `Student` entities stored in different tables in the database?

Comment: Have you tried with sequences in sql server ?

Comment: Both Leraar and Student are stored under Gebruiker Table.

Comment: Doesn't entityframework support sequences? Through attributes or something? Would be a very useful feature.